# Add marker to map from JSON, Android

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I was trying to add markers to a map automatically after getting the data from JSON, with the position that is in the api, this is what I have:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpHandler sh2 = new HttpHandler();
        final String jsonStrOportunidades = sh2.makeServiceCall(urlOportunidades);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from URL: " + jsonStrOportunidades);
        if (jsonStrOportunidades != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStrOportunidades);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String Designacao = jsonObject.getString("Designacao");
                    String Coord_LAT = jsonObject.getString("Coord_LAT");
                    String Coord_LONG = jsonObject.getString("Coord_LONG");

                    HashMap<String, String> oportunidades = new HashMap<>();

                    oportunidades.put("Designacao", Designacao);
                    oportunidades.put("Coord_LAT", Coord_LAT);
                    oportunidades.put("Coord_LONG", Coord_LONG);

                    double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(Coord_LAT);
                    double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(Coord_LONG);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)));

                    listaOportunidades.add(oportunidades);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parsin error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } 
        return null;
    }
```

"mMap.addMarker" doesn't work, is it even possible creating markers from there?

Comment: what exception or error you getting?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2

Comment: @alb Please [edit] your question with the full exception in the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the marker from `onPostExecute`. `doInBackground` isn't the place to update UI components.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    HttpHandler sh2 = new HttpHandler();
    final String jsonStrOportunidades = sh2.makeServiceCall(urlOportunidades);
    Log.e(TAG, "Response from URL: " + jsonStrOportunidades);

    return jsonStrOportunidades;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String jsonStrOportunidades){

  if (jsonStrOportunidades != null) {
      try {
          JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStrOportunidades);
          for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
              String Designacao = jsonObject.getString("Designacao");
              String Coord_LAT = jsonObject.getString("Coord_LAT");
              String Coord_LONG = jsonObject.getString("Coord_LONG");

              HashMap<String, String> oportunidades = new HashMap<>();

              oportunidades.put("Designacao", Designacao);
              oportunidades.put("Coord_LAT", Coord_LAT);
              oportunidades.put("Coord_LONG", Coord_LONG);

              double lat1 = Double.parseDouble(Coord_LAT);
              double lng1 = Double.parseDouble(Coord_LONG);

              mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)));

              listaOportunidades.add(oportunidades);
          }
      } catch (final JSONException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parsin error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  } 

}
```

Also, you need to change the AsyncTask class like this

```
YourAsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

Comment: onPostExecute already runs on the UI thread. You don't need it there to Toast

Comment: It worked just had to change "protected void doInBackground(Void... params) " to "public String doInBackground(Object... params)". Thanks!

Comment: @cricket_007 Right! That was silly of me. Thanks for pointing that out.


And alb Yeah, another novice mistake. Typed the code in Atom and naturally it didn't arise any return type error so it slipped my eye. Thanks for pointing that out.

I updated my code based on the input of both of you.